# Handling async promises inside if statements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am dealing with the following scenario in javascript. `tt` resembles a function from a package that return reject promise if something didn't happen. I want to **Booleanize** the `await tt()` in the `test()` function if that reject promise is triggered. the current setup results in catching the error and the `else()` block is not executed. is there a way to overcome that?

```
async function tt(){
  
  return Promise.reject('failed');
  
}


async function test(){
  
  if (somecondition && await tt()) //assume somecondition is true    
  {
    console.log("accept")
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("reject")
  }
    
}

test()
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

I want to avoid using `.then(res ... ).catch(err ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `tt` in your own function that catches the error:

```
async function wrapped_tt() {
  try {
    await tt();
    return true; // or return await tt(); depending on what tt returns
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

later

```
if (somecondition && await wrapped_tt()) {
```

Of course you may want to check the error thrown by `tt` and only decide to return `false` for some of those errors.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't care about the resolved value or the rejection error? Sure:

```
async function tt() {
  return Promise.reject("failed");
}

function promiseAsBoolean(p) {
  return p.then((s) => true, (e) => false);
}

async function test() {
  if (somecondition && (await promiseAsBoolean(tt()))) {
    console.log("accept");
  } else {
    console.log("reject");
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect! I was trying to do `p.then((s) => return true, (e) => return false);` but now I know the syntax!